# autocomplete="off" em input type "password" é necessário? Por que?

Tags: html

Um dos sistemas que trabalho foi analisado por uma equipe de segurança e entre algumas práticas de segurança que recomendaram, estava a inclusão do `autocomplete="off"` em elementos `input` do tipo `password`.

Gostaria de saber se este procedimento seria desnecessário, sendo que os browsers já "sabem" que se trata de um campo de inserção de senha e provavelmente (eu acho) eles não irão habilitar o `autocomplete`.

Exemplo:

```
<input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off">
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alguns navegadores implementam o gerenciamento de senhas; quando ele digita uma senha no formulário o navegador dá a opção de salvá-la, quando o site é visitado novamente, o campo é autopreenchido. Ainda por cima, o navegador permite ao usuário escolher uma "senha mestra" que será usada para criptografar os dados armazenados.

Por isso, alguns navegadores não suportam o `autocomplete="off"`.

1. Se você definir o autocomplete em um campo de senha por exemplo, o browser vai permitir que o usuário salve a senha para a próxima vez que o usuário visite a página. *Está ai o porquê de em alguns navegadores não funcionar.*
2. Isso ocorre no Firefox (desde a versão 38), Google Chrome (desde a 34) e Internet Explorer (a partir da versão 11).

Em alguns casos, o browser vai manter o autocomplete para completar automaticamente, mesmo se o atributo estiver definido como `off`.

O correto que sua equipe de segurança deveria recomendar seria o `autocomplete="nope"`. Uma vez que este valor aleatório não é um [valor válido](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-autocomplete), então o navegador vai desistir de preenchê-lo.

Essa é uma questão única do cliente, se o cliente seleciona salvar a senha, o navegador vai dar prioridade para ele.

Realmente isso é discutível. Estarei fazendo uma leitura mais ampla e estarei editando essa resposta.

Libraria:

[Segurança - Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)